# MySql query for "Following/Follower" system, [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi guys i am making follower/followed system using MySQL and PHP, So I want to fetch all videos of my followed users  and order by ID desc.

Database schema:
[image]

For example if my `user_id = 1`, and if i am following users with `user_id = 3; 5;` I want to see only videos from `publisher_id = 3; 5;`

Comment: thank you for edit Chris, Yes my problem is this, i dont know to make query with JOIN's.. .

Comment: `select * from user_followers as uf join videos as v on uf.followed_id = v.publisher_id where uf.follower_id = ? order by video_id desc` Yes this is working thank you Chris.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`join`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to get the tables linked together then a `where` to limit the videos to just your followers.

```
select * 
from user_followers as uf 
join videos as v 
on uf.followed_id = v.publisher_id 
where uf.follower_id = ?
```

> Generally, the `ON` clause serves for conditions that specify how to join tables, and the `WHERE` clause restricts which rows to include in the result set.